# how to find a vowel inside a string in c++?

Tags: c++, string

how to find a vowel inside a string in c++? do I use "a" or 'a' or just the ascii value to look or vowels?

Comment: You could use `"a"` or `'a'`, depending on how you do it. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried both also tried with the ascii values, but no luck.

Comment: If you post the code you tried, we'll have a better chance of helping you.

Comment: Do you need to see if the string contains any vowels, return the positions of all the vowels, modify the vowels, or do something else?

Comment: for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
   {
       if(s[i]==('a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u'))
       {
           s.replace(i,1,"u");
       }

   }

Comment: @MokammelSanju: Your if statement doesn't do what you think it does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::find_first_of` algorithm:

```
string h="hello world"; 
string v="aeiou"; 
cout << *find_first_of(h.begin(), h.end(), v.begin(), v.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int is_vowel(char c) {
    switch(c)
    {
        // check for capitalized forms as well.
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    const char *str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    while(char c = *str++) {
        if(is_vowel(c))
            // it's a vowel
    }
}
```

EDIT: Oops, C++.  Here is a `std::string` version.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool is_vowel(char c) {
    switch(c)
    {
        // check for capitalized forms as well.
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
        if(is_vowel(str[i]))
            std::cout << str[i];
    }

    char n;
    std::cin >> n;
}
```

Comment: for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
   {
       if(s[i]==('a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u'))
       {
           s.replace(i,1,"u");
       }

   }

Comment: @MokammelSanju: Well `if(s[i]==('a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u')` is wrong (doesn't do what you seem to think it does), and I'm not sure why you're replacing characters (it wasn't stated as a requirement), but I suppose I should have assumed `std::string` instead of `const char*` as this is tagged C++.

Comment: yeah, it I am using the code for c++ and I have used std::string in in the same code previously.Any idea how do I find vowels then?

Comment: @MokammelSanju: Did you read my response?  That function finds vowels in a string.

Comment: sorry guys, I am new here I am not familiar with how stuff work here.

Comment: Yeah I did read it if you are talking about the code you posted. But I can not use a custom function, I have to use a built in one.

Comment: Well you can always take the logic out of the function.  There is no standard function to tell you if a character is a vowel.

Comment: why is my if statement wrong? PS: all the characters in the string are lowercase.

Comment: yeah I know that, what I am saying is what is the logic to find a vowel?

Comment: What about `'A'`?  What about `'y'`?  Not that it's the answer that the OP is looking for, but the question has no real answer (or else a very, very complex) one.  (With regards to the answer he's looking for, I'd use a table rather than a switch.  But both will get the job done for a naive definition of vowel.)

Comment: @MokammelSanju: The switch statement is the logic.  Think of it as an if statement if you're not familiar with them.  It checks a character and, if it is a vowel (`aeio` or `u`), returns `true` from the function.  Otherwise it returns `false`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yeah, I didn't intend it to cover every possible scenario. Honestly, it doesn't take a large leap of logic to account for capital letters.  Of course it has a simple answer. This program doesn't need to take into account every possible complication, it is a simple homework assignment.

Comment: I think I figured it out, apparently this works......if((s[i]=='a')||(s[i]=='e')||(s[i]=='i')||(s[i]=='o')||(s[i]=='u'))

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string vowels = "aeiou";
std::string target = "How now, brown cow?"
std::string::size_type pos = target.find_first_of(vowels);
```

Note that this does not use `std::find_first_of`, but the `string` member function with the same name. It's possible that the implementation provides an optimized version for string searches.